# Retrieve 40.7288 from 2240.7288 (miss first two values)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, gmap.net

I'm converting digital minute values to digital degrees (longitude and latitude), how would I come about retrieving all values apart from the first two? From here I can calculate values, such as 5322.72233N and 00127.5333W, to another format. I've looked at Math.Truncate ([Best way to get whole number part of a Decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479706/best-way-to-get-whole-number-part-of-a-decimal-number)).

Let's calculate latitude **5322.72233**

- 22.72233 / 60
- +53
- Final result is **53.3787055**

Calculating the longitude with value **00127.5333**

*(Along the lines of... (calculation hasn't been checked thoroughly yet))*

- 27.5333 / 60
- +1
- x -1
- Final result

I'm sure it's simple.

Comment: Is there always 2 leading digits to drop? Because your second number has 5 digits before the decimal place so would you want 127 or 27?

Comment: I've updated my question, the points dropped are always the ones on the left of the decimal point. It would be 27, not 127.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use the [`%` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) (modulus) to remove any digits beyond `100` like this:

```
var input = 5322.72233m;
var output = input % 100m; // 22.72233
```

From that point the rest of the math should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to get the remainder as follows:

```
double a = 5322.72233;
double b = 100;
double c = a % b;
```

Next:

```
c = c / 60 + 53;  // 53.3787055
```