# How to convert decimal to int in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model properties which is of decimal type, I have an edit form. This form has textboxes which shows values ends with .0, i wanted to remove this.0 from it. How to do that.

```
 public Nullable<decimal> PhoneNumber { get; set; }
 public Nullable<int> MeetingPinLength { get; set; }
```

Comment: what if that value has like this `25.365` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479706/best-way-to-get-whole-number-part-of-a-decimal-number

Comment: value will always be like 25365 not with decimal i cannot change edmx i need another option to do that

Comment: Tha is actually mvc view editorfor

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var aliasstart = document.getElementById('AliasStart').value; 
        document.getElementById('AliasStart').value = Math.floor(aliasstart);

        var aliasstart1 = document.getElementById('AliasStep').value;
        document.getElementById('AliasStep').value = Math.floor(aliasstart1);

        var aliasstart2 = document.getElementById('AliasEnd').value;
        document.getElementById('AliasEnd').value = Math.floor(aliasstart2);

        var aliasstart3 = document.getElementById('PhoneNumber').value;
        document.getElementById('PhoneNumber').value = Math.floor(aliasstart3);

        var aliasstart4 = document.getElementById('PhoneNumber').value;
        document.getElementById('PhoneNumber').value = Math.floor(aliasstart4);



    });
</script>
```